# NPM link keeps pulling old version even after npm clean cache --force, unlink, rm -rf node_modules, etc

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a package foo, which I want to symlink and use the local version of foo in package bar.

Normal process should be (I think)

1. in foo run sudo npm link
2. in bar run sudo npm link foo

Done

Bar keeps pulling an old version of foo however, not the version that is on my local machine. This old version doesn't appear to exist anywhere and isn't the live verison

I have tried

```
npm clean cache --force
```

in foo:

```
npm unlink
rm -rf node modules, rm -rf build, rm -rf dist, rm -rf package-lock.json 
npm build
npm link
```

in bar:

```
npm link foo
rm -rf node modules, rm -rf build, rm -rf dist, rm -rf package-lock.json 
npm build
```

Bar still ends up with the old version of foo that is neither the current local version or the live version. Where could this old version be living, and why does it keep coming back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't clear out your `package-lock.json` file then npm will try to install the exact versions of the dependencies that are listed in `package-lock.json`. See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json

Try deleting `package-lock.json` before cleaning and re-installing your packages.

Comment: Problem persists for me. :')